# Number is convert in string during interval running?

Tags: jquery

I need to update a div value with jquery interval. But when I run it, its working fine first time. But when it run again after 2000(ms) it returns `NaN` instead of value. If anyone knows how to solve this error please help me.

My Code example is here

```
var div = $('#records_crawled').text();

//alert(div);
var cur = '';
//console.log(cur);
setInterval(function () {
    cur = parseInt(div)+ parseInt(1);
    div = $('#records_crawled').text(parseInt(cur));
    console.log(div);
}, 2000); // time in miliseconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at this line: `div = $('#records_crawled').text(parseInt(cur));`

You have to split this line in two separate lines like this:

```
  $('#records_crawled').text(cur);
  div = cur;
```

Your code also needs some clean-ups and the final code will be like this:

```
var div = parseInt($('#records_crawled').text());

var cur = '';
//console.log(cur);
setInterval(function () {
    cur = div + 1;
    $('#records_crawled').text(cur);
    div = cur;
    console.log(div);
}, 2000); // time in miliseconds.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time. i use your code in my code know its return [Object Object]1. And i didn't understand why its returning this did you know any other way to fix this error.

Comment: @UsmanAli Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0p3sc0u8/) It's working perfectly here. Maybe you have something in your code which have not shared in your question and that is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks Brother Really thanks. I saw i missed one thing in my code thanks again.

Comment: @UsmanAli You are welcome, if this answer has helped you to solve your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it and also give it an up-vote :)